# html image is not appearing

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title> Cookie Clicker! </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var logAt=function(id,message){
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=message;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Cookie Clicker </h1>
<p> Keep collecting cookies and start your very own sweet empire!</p>
<p>
<div id="cookiesPerSecond"> </div>
<button type="button" onClick="getCookie()"><img src="http://thinkprogress.org/politics/2011/04/26/161276/penn-parents-cookies-cuts/" alt="Cookie"
style="width:304px;height:228px"></button>
<h3 id="cookies">Cookies:0 </h3>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cookies=0;
var cookiesPerSecond=0;
function getCookie(){
cookies+=1;
logAt("cookies","Cookies:"+cookies);
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My image inside of the button is not displaying, and defaults to the "alt". I am programming this on notepad, and am opening it in chrome. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: `http://thinkprogress.org/politics/2011/04/26/161276/penn-parents-cookies-cuts/` is not an image. Also use a background-image for your button.

Comment: Roko, you should consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: Yup, your code works as expected when you use an image: http://jsfiddle.net/bvhtmuce/

Answer (score 0):

What you linked is not a link to a direct image. You need to link directly to an image. This is the link you need to change:

```
<img src="http://thinkprogress.org/politics/2011/04/26/161276/penn-parents-cookies-cuts/"
```

Change it to this:

```
<img src="http://d35brb9zkkbdsd.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/cookie.gif"
```

Also, like User Roko C. Bulijan said, you need to use CSS to make it a background-image or it won't show up.